# Is it possible to upload screenshots for both iOS6 and iOS7, for App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios7, app-store-connect

I am going to upload an update to my app in **iTunes Connect**, now supporting both iOS6 and iOS7. Before I am "ready to upload binary", I want to edit 'metadata and uploads' to contain screenshots for both versions.

The problem is I am only let to upload to "3.5-inch Retina Display", "4-inch Retina Display" and "iPad" *(see screenshot below)*. **There is no way I can choose for which iOS certain screenshots should be shown.**

Am I doing something wring or is Apple´s intention that only iOS7 screenshots should be displayed in App Store?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify screenshots to be shown depending on the iOS version, however, the screenshots that you do post can be taken from any iOS version. So feel free to mix and match if you wish, or consider photoshopping a banner on them that says "Looks beautiful in both iOS 6 and iOS 7"

Answer (score 2):

you can upload your screenshots regardless of the version ios. I have an application that has four screenshots ios7 and one of iOS6 and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way of choosing iOS Screenshots . I too uploaded one app but there is no choice to choose iOS Screenshots .

Comment: Strange. So you just used iOS7 screenshots?

Comment: Yes Uploaded iOS 7 Screen shots